# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

При запуске Spring Boot вылетает такой Exception. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить? Спасибо.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor':     
 Injection of autowired dependencies failed nested exception is      
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    
 org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.
 forAnnotations([Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)
 Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
 AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues
 (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:355) 
 ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]

<properties>
    <jstl>1.2</jstl>
    <Gson>2.7</Gson>
    <log4j>1.2.17</log4j>
    <servlet.api>3.1.0</servlet.api>
    <spring.boot>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot>
    <hibernate>4.3.11.Final</hibernate>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <spring.mvc>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <mySqlConnector>5.1.34</mySqlConnector>
    <hibernateJpa>1.0.0.Final</hibernateJpa>
    <commons.fileupload>1.3.1</commons.fileupload>
    <spring.securiry>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.securiry>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.api}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.fileupload}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mySqlConnector}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateJpa}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${Gson}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: происходит по причине не согласованности версий библиотек. Класс библиотеки А требует от класса библиотеки Б метод Х , а его там нету. Проверте на предмет версий библиотек(обычно в документации написано какой либе какую надо версию другой либы).

Comment: я проверял, вроде бы все последние версии...

Comment: Смотрите не на предмет свежести, а согласованности. Проверте на совместимость :  <spring.boot>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot>
    <spring.mvc>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <spring.securiry>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.securiry>